# Sending a SMS from a foreground service

Tags: android, permissions, sms

I have a geofenching app which allows the user to enable an option to send a SMS to a preprogrammed number while he is away from the device. This happens in a foreground service.

When the user activates this option in the settings, I start the process to request the required permission:

```
   if (key.equals(getString(R.string.pref_sms_alert)))
    {
        if (Prefs.getBoolean(R.string.pref_sms_alert, false))
        {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}, 1);
            }
        }
    }
```

and

```
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults)
{
    switch (requestCode)
    {
        case 1:
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                Prefs.put(R.string.pref_sms_alert, true);
            }
            else
            {
                Prefs.put(R.string.pref_sms_alert, false);
            }
            break;


    }
}
```

The SMS is sent in the foreground service by:

```
    if (Prefs.getBoolean(R.string.pref_sms_alert, false))
    {
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(Prefs.getString(R.string.pref_sms_receiver, ""),
                                    null,
                                    getString(R.string.txt_sms_alert),
                                   null, null);
    }
```

This works which Android 6+.

When I try this with an older version (Kitkat) the user is requested to give permission, when the SMS is sent. What he cannot do because he is not at the device.

How can I give permanent permission to send SMS prior to Android 6 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a problem of the specific device used for testing.
There is a 3rd party permission management software installed that asked again for permissions, when the SMS actually was sent.

I tested it on a Lollypop device without this software and I had no problems.

Answer (score 0):

Apps that are pre-Api 23 accept all permissions on install, not in runtime. So the issue is that `onRequestPermissionsResult` is only called when the permission is granted. If the app already has the permission then that method is not called, so add this:

```
if (key.equals(getString(R.string.pref_sms_alert)))
{
    if (Prefs.getBoolean(R.string.pref_sms_alert, false))
    {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}, 1);
        } else
        {
            Prefs.put(R.string.pref_sms_alert, true);
        }
    }
}
```

This way if the permission is already owned by the app, it will still work.

Comment: The else-branch you added would not change anything as the preference is already true at this point. But it is a moot point anyway as the problem was quite a different one - see my answer below.